# How to stop slider when hover in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

Im stuck with javascript part.please help me to solve this. I want to stop slider animation when mouse hover.

this is my code. i used worpresstheme. then slider load with wordpress part. how can i stop slider when mouse hover.

```
 $query=new WP_Query($args);

            if($query->have_posts()) {
            $hasSliderEmpty=false;


            echo '<div class="slides-container">';  
                echo '<div onmousemove="myMoveFunction()" onmouseout="myOutFunction" id="home_slider">
                    <section class="autoheight home_slider">
                        <section class="inner-slider">
                            <div id="slider_562472b018d72">
                                <div class="slides-container">';
                                    $c=0;
                                    while($query->have_posts()) {
                                        $query->the_post();

                                        echo get_the_post_thumbnail(get_the_ID(),'large');

                                    }

                                    global $wpdb;
                                    $vimeoLink= $wpdb->get_var("SELECT meta_value FROM fts_postmeta WHERE post_id = '$event_id' and meta_key='_event_after_movie_link'");
                                    if($vimeoLink != ''){
                    //echo $vimeoLink;
                                        echo '<iframe src="//player.vimeo.com/video/'.$vimeoLink.'" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>';
                                    }

                                echo '</div>';
                            echo '</div>
                        <div class="col-lg-12 landing-text-pos image_content wow animated fadeInDown" data-wow-duration="1s" data-wow-delay="1s" style="top:35%;">
                            <div class="slider_inner_content">
                                <div class="container align-center" style="padding-top:15px;">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                            window.globalSlides = "#slider_562472b018d72";
                            window.globalSliderSpeed = "5000";
                            window.globalSlidesActive = "yes";
                        </script>
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                            window.globalHeaderTransparentActive = "yes";


                        </script>

                        </section>
                    </section>
                </div>
            </div>';
            ?>
```

Comment: `onmousemove="myMoveFunction()" onmouseout="myOutFunction"` I think that's where mouseenter mouseleave are implemented. Is there any code related to myMoveFunction() and / or myOutFunction ?

Comment: no i try this function to stop slider. but i failed. what is the code inside inside myMoveFunction() to stop slider? i reduce slider speed . but it doesn't work.

Comment: I can't really say, the code you posted lacks basic info about the slider itself. Can you tell me what's the slider? Flexslider, revoslider...?

Comment: actually i posted some images from wordpress backend and slide them using while loop.
 actually i try mymovefunction() with alert. it worked! but i dont know how to stop slider..

Comment: please edit your post, try to re-include those screenshots.